# Can't get updated text file from another server. What is the cause of this?

Tags: caching, text, curl, get, file-get-contents

I am trying to get a frequently updated text file from another server like http://site2.com/state.txt with cURL or PHP's file_get_contents() function.

With both two ways, after a few requests I'm getting previous file instead of getting the updated one.

If I change the file path like http://www.site2.com/state.txt it gets the updated file for a while and again starts to get the old content.

What can I do for getting the updated file countinuosly?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I dont know php nor do I know curl, but I believe I know a browser caching issue when I see one.

When your browser sees the same get request request multiple times it serves you up a cached version instead of going and actually performing the request.

Two ways to fix:

1. Clear your browser cache every time you want to get the updated file.  (That's a joke)
2. When you make your get request you should append some sort of time stamp to the end of your url.

I would do this in javascript.

```
var url = "http://www.site2.com/state.txt?_=" + now();
```

So basically I am appending a parameter named '_' to the end of the request that has the value of the current timestamp.  This will cause the browser to perform a new get request and not give you the cached version.

Comment: Hey just checking in.  Did you get a chance to try this out?